# Desktop Weather Display using Pi-pico-w

Tags: python, pi-pico, micropython, pi-pico-w

I'm trying to replicate this (https://mustardcorner.com/desktop-weather) project but I'm trying to use the Pico w instead of the Pizero w he was using.

But the code obviously does not work on the Pico, would anyone know how I could adapt it to work on the Pico? This is the code from his website:

Weather API

```
import json
import requests
import datetime as datetime

token = ""
lat = ""
lon = ""

api_request_url_onecall = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude=minutely&appid={token}&units=metric"


def get_weather_forecast():

    data = requests.get(api_request_url_onecall)
    readable_json = json.loads(data.content)
    print(data.text)

    def print_time(timestamp):
        print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
        return

    # https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
    # you can use this mapping table to tailor the weather conditions
    # for example, you may consider 10% clouds to be "Clear" and 25% clouds or more to be "Cloudy"...

    def weather_lookup(id):
        if id in range(800, 803):  # we consider below 50% clouds to be "Clear"...
            return "Clear"
        elif id in range(803, 805):
            return "Clouds"
        elif id in range(700, 800):
            return "Mist"
        elif id in range(600, 700):
            return "Snow"
        elif id in range(500, 600):
            return "Rain"
        elif id in range(300, 400):
            return "Rain"
        elif id in range(200, 300):
            return "Thunderstorm"
        else:
            return "Mist"

    #  current time
    print_time(readable_json["current"]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["current"]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["current"]["weather"][0]["id"])
    current_weather = (weather_lookup(readable_json["current"]["weather"][0]["id"]))
    print(current_weather)

    #  3rd hour from now
    print_time(readable_json["hourly"][3]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][3]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][3]["weather"][0]["id"])
    threehr_weather = weather_lookup(readable_json["hourly"][3]["weather"][0]["id"])
    print(threehr_weather)


    #  6th hour from now
    print_time(readable_json["hourly"][6]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][6]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][6]["weather"][0]["id"])
    sixhr_weather = weather_lookup(readable_json["hourly"][6]["weather"][0]["id"])
    print(sixhr_weather)

    #  12th hour from now
    print_time(readable_json["hourly"][12]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][12]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["hourly"][12]["weather"][0]["id"])
    twelvehr_weather = weather_lookup(readable_json["hourly"][12]["weather"][0]["id"])
    print(twelvehr_weather)

    #  tomorrow at midday
    print_time(readable_json["daily"][1]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["daily"][1]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["daily"][1]["weather"][0]["id"])
    tomorrow_weather = weather_lookup(readable_json["daily"][1]["weather"][0]["id"])
    print(tomorrow_weather)

    #  two days at midday
    print_time(readable_json["daily"][2]["dt"])
    print(readable_json["daily"][2]["weather"][0]["main"])
    print(readable_json["daily"][2]["weather"][0]["id"])
    twodays_weather = weather_lookup(readable_json["daily"][2]["weather"][0]["id"])
    print(twodays_weather)

    weather_list = [current_weather, threehr_weather, sixhr_weather, twelvehr_weather, tomorrow_weather, twodays_weather]
    return weather_list
```

Main code

```
from weather_api import get_weather_forecast

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime as datetime

GPIO.cleanup()


servo_pin_1 = 18
servo_pin_2 = 23
button_pin = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servo_pin_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(servo_pin_2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

servo_1 = GPIO.PWM(servo_pin_1, 50) # GPIO 17 for PWM with 50Hz
servo_2 = GPIO.PWM(servo_pin_2, 50) # GPIO 17 for PWM with 50Hz

servo_1.start(2)
servo_2.start(12)
time.sleep(0.8)

servo_1.start(12)
servo_2.start(2)
time.sleep(0.8)

servo_1.start(2)
servo_2.start(12)
time.sleep(0.8)

servo_1.start(6)
servo_2.start(6)
time.sleep(0.8)

servo_1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
servo_2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
time.sleep(.4)


positions = {"Clear": 11.9,
               "Clouds": 10.1,
               "Rain": 8,
               "Thunderstorm": 5.9,
               "Snow": 3.9,
               "Mist": 2.1,

               "Now": 12,
               "3hr": 10.2,
               "6hr": 8.5,
               "12hr": 6,
               "24hr": 4,
               "48hr": 2.5}

def move_servo(servo_1_position, servo_2_position):
    servo_1_new_position = positions[servo_1_position]
    servo_2_new_position = positions[servo_2_position]
    
    servo_1.ChangeDutyCycle(servo_1_new_position)
    servo_2.ChangeDutyCycle(servo_2_new_position)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    servo_1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    servo_2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    time.sleep(0.5)

def print_servo(servo, position): #  used for testing only
    new_position = positions[position]
    print(f"Servo: {servo} Position: {new_position}")


class Timer:
    value = 0
    max_value = (10 * 60) * 5

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0

    def tick(self):
        refresh = False

        if self.value >= Timer.max_value:
            self.reset()
            refresh = True

        self.value += 1
        time.sleep(0.09)
        return refresh


def weather_toggle(current_weather_displayed):
    if current_weather_displayed >= max_weather_displayable:
        current_weather_displayed = 0
    else:
        current_weather_displayed += 1
    return current_weather_displayed

global last_refreshed_weather
last_refreshed_weather = datetime.datetime.now()
weather_list = get_weather_forecast() 

def refresh_weather_data(current_weather_displayed, weather_list):
    global last_refreshed_weather
    the_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f"last refresh: {last_refreshed_weather} - time now: {the_time}")
    if the_time >= last_refreshed_weather + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20):
        print("getting new weather from API")
        weather_list = get_weather_forecast()
        last_refreshed_weather = the_time
    else:
        print("using old data, no refresh needed")
    weathers = [
        {"time": "Now", "weather": weather_list[0]},
        {"time": "3hr", "weather": weather_list[1]},
        {"time": "6hr", "weather": weather_list[2]},
        {"time": "12hr", "weather": weather_list[3]},
        {"time": "24hr", "weather": weather_list[4]},
        {"time": "48hr", "weather": weather_list[5]}
    ]
    weather_to_display = weathers[current_weather_displayed]
    return weather_to_display, weather_list


def get_input():
    if GPIO.input(button_pin) == GPIO.LOW:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def update_display(weather_to_display):
    print(f"{current_weather_displayed} - {weather_to_display['time']}: {weather_to_display['weather']}")
    print_servo(servo_1, weather_to_display["time"])
    print_servo(servo_2, (weather_to_display["weather"]))
    move_servo((weather_to_display["time"]), (weather_to_display["weather"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    current_weather_displayed = 0  # make weather display the current weather the first time
    weather_to_display, weather_list = refresh_weather_data(current_weather_displayed, weather_list)
    update_display(weather_to_display)
    max_weather_displayable = 5
    

    timer = Timer()
    print("Ready")
    while True:

        if get_input() is True:
            timer.reset()
            current_weather_displayed = weather_toggle(current_weather_displayed)
            weather_to_display, weather_list = refresh_weather_data(current_weather_displayed, weather_list)
            update_display(weather_to_display)

        refresh = timer.tick()

        #print(timer.value)
        if refresh is True:
            current_weather_displayed = weather_toggle(current_weather_displayed)
            weather_to_display, weather_list = refresh_weather_data(current_weather_displayed, weather_list)
            update_display(weather_to_display)
```

I would much appreciate any help Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Well the code is written in python, but the pico uses micro-python which dosnt support python requests etc

Comment: So what have you tried in terms of MicroPython already, and what specific issues are you having?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, well I tried swapping the requests module for urequests and time for utime,but that didn't work. So my problem is that some of the packages used in the code aren't compatible with micropython and I'm not sure what to use instead or how to use them